# wp_nav_menu: show menu only if one exists, otherwise show nothing

Tags: menus, pages, list

I'm trying to use wp_nav_menu to only display a menu if one exists, otherwise, display nothing.

If I delete the menu, it will output a list of the pages.

My functions.php file contains:

```
if (function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
register_nav_menus (
array('main_nav' => 'Main Navigation Menu'));}
```

How can I use wp_nav_menu to only display a menu if one exists, otherwise show nothing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`has_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu), and test for `theme_location`, rather than `menu_id`:

```
<?php
if ( has_nav_menu( $theme_location ) ) {
    // User has assigned menu to this location;
    // output it
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'theme_location' => $theme_location, 
        'menu_class' => 'nav', 
        'container' => '' 
    ) );
}
?>
```

You can output alternate content, by adding an `else` clause.

**EDIT**

You need to replace `$theme_location` with your *actual* `theme_location`:

```
<?php
if ( has_nav_menu( 'main_nav' ) ) {
    // User has assigned menu to this location;
    // output it
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'theme_location' => 'main_nav', 
        'menu_class' => 'nav', 
        'container' => '' 
    ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: While this outputs nothing if there's no menu, it unfortunately does the same when there *is* a menu. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you applied a menu to the specified Theme Location?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus`. Create and save a custom menu, then apply it to the specified Theme Location, using the dropdown menu.

Comment: Ah yes, I had done that (screenshot: http://bit.ly/vrjNf9). Unfortunately, the problem still persists - the menu won't appear. P.S. My functions file has this:  if (function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
 register_nav_menus (
  array('main_nav' => 'Main Navigation Menu'));}

Comment: Can you update your question with your actual, current output code?

Comment: See updated answer; in case you took my shorthand a bit literally, I clarified the `wp_nav_menu()` call's arguments array. :)

Comment: I updated the question with your updated code, but it still won't output the menu (it's not outputting any HTML at all). Anything else I can try?

Comment: You have to use your *actual Theme Location*, e.g. `main_nav`, not the placeholder variable `$theme_location`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can just specify false as the `fallback_cb` argument of `wp_nav_menu`.  Nothing will show up -- rather, wp_nav_menu will return false (echoing nothing out).

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array( 
    'theme_location' => $main_nav, 
    'menu_class'     => 'nav', 
    'container'      => '',
    'fallback_cb'    => false
));
```

Comment: It seems not : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#more-information

Comment: That was lifesaving! Ah it was driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just register menu firstly without specifying the location.
In `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {  
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'header' => __( 'Header Menu' )
        )
    );
}
```

And when you call the menu in `header.php`, check with [`has_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu):

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'header' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) ); 
}
```

Comment: If you register a menu **without** a theme location, you cannot ask for it later **with** a theme location restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

set 'fallback_cb' => false and none will be displayed, this is the standard method suggested by wp guys.

Comment: This is the same as chrisguitarguy answer...

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point you out to the main article on wordpress codex.

Comment: It seems that it is not true. The docs says: 

If not given a theme_location parameter, the function displays
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#more-information
the menu matching the ID, slug, or name given by the menu parameter;
otherwise, the first non-empty menu;
otherwise (or if the menu given by menu is empty), output of the function given by the fallback_cb parameter (wp_page_menu(), by default);
otherwise nothing.